# filenot found exception for mscorlib.dll

Tags: .net

i have installer project working fine on development machine(32 bit) but when i move it to the production server it crashes. the error is related to mscorlib.dll(file not found exception  clr20r3). the snapshot of exception for ur refrence is attached. 
i have tried repairing/ re installing framework 3.5.[image]

Answer (score 1):

i was trying to retrive sql servers present in networks. on my development machine sqlserver is installed but not on production server. so it was crashing on server. after adding 3 more dlls to output folder it is working fine. 
1. Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
2.Microsoft.SqlServer.smoenum
3. Microsoft.SqlServer.rmo
4.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.sqlEnum